# What is the loss function for C - Support Vector Classification?

Tags: svm, libsvm, loss-functions

In article [LIBSVM: A Library for Support Vector Machines](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) it is written that C-SVC uses the loss function

$$ \frac{1}{2}w^Tw+C\sum\limits_{i=1}^l\xi_i$$

I know what is $w^Tw$.

But what is $\xi_i$?  I know that it is somehow connected with misclassifications, but how it is calculated exactly?

P.S. I don't use any non-linear kernels.

Answer (score 3):

$\xi_i$ are the slack variables. They are typically nonzero when the 2-class data is non-separable. We are trying the minimize the slack as much as possible (by minimizing their sum, since they are non-negative) along with maximizing the margin ($w^Tw$) term.

*Exact calculation*: Well, if the convex program has been solved to optimality without any optimization error, then yes, they are calculated exactly.

Comment: I know, that they are typically nonzero when the 2-class data is non-separable.
I know, that we are trying to minimize their sum.
But I don't know, what is the loss function they are calculated with. Is it a step function or hinge loss or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is the hinge loss. The hinge loss has been removed from the objective and made into a bunch of constraints (their number equalt to the number of examples, $l$ in your notation). In particular, $\max[0,1-y_iw^Tx_i]$ is the loss on example $i$.

Comment: @Theja can you explain how wTw term is same as maximum margin?